# How to publish an Internet Exporer BHO Addon to ieGallery.com

Tags: internet-explorer, wix, bho, ieaddon

I have successfully developed and tested an Internet Explorer BHO Add-on for my local machine. I want to publish this to the Internet Explorer Gallery @ http://www.iegallery.com/AddOns/Edit. There is no option under **Type** for BHO so I am *assuming* that my BHO would fall under the **Toolbars** tab. However it is asking me for the *Extension File*. I am not sure what this would be considered. I have searched and searched for relevant information, and even tried to use their contact link to ask them directly, but as usual Microsoft makes everything extra difficult and I was unsuccessful.

So my question is this:

Do I need to create an installer package and upload this as the Extension file, or are they asking for the Visual Studio Project Solution file? ( *highly unlikely I think* )

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an installer and upload it under "Toolbars [and extensions]".

If you want to see how other add-ons are listing themselves, follow the following steps:

1. If you're not using Internet Explorer, change your user agent string to a IE.
2. Go to http://www.iegallery.com/.
3. Hover over "Filter by add-on type" and select "toolbars".
4. Click on "all".
5. Select any result, e.g. [Adblock Plus](http://www.iegallery.com/Addons/Details/16161).

The [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) can be used to build a MSI. Do not forget to test your installer/BHO on different versions of Windows, processor architectures and Internet Explorer versions to make sure that you're not accidentally uploading broken software.

## My experience on submitting an item to IEGallery.com

I've recently submitted [Lyrics Here](https://robwu.nl/lyricshere/) to the Internet Explorer Gallery. Without any code changes, it was approved after two rejections.

After [submitting](http://www.iegallery.com/addons/Details/16391) the extension for the first time, it was rejected after three days. I received the following generic mail message from `no-reply@iegallery.com`:

> Thanks for your submission to the Internet Explorer Gallery.  Your Toolbar or Extension was not posted due to the following reason:
>
> There is currently a lack of community demand for this add-on scenario.
>
> There is not currently a demand for this item in the gallery at this time. Thanks for your interest.
>
> Regards,
> Internet
> Explorer Gallery Team

I was quite surprised! Then I edited my add-on description to emphasize that the add-on has over 30k users in the 5 major browsers, combined. It was rejected again (after 4 days).

<sub>(when I looked in the access log files in my server, I saw no visits to the mentioned homepage, so I guess that the reviewers at IEGallery.com are approving/rejecting an add-on solely by the name, description and screenshot (and *maybe* also the extension you've added to the submission)).</sub>

### Road to success

I created a [**new addon submission**](http://www.iegallery.com/addons/Details/16396) (since there's no way to contact them by mail or at a forum). In the "Name" field, I entered "Reply to add-on rejection", and in the "Description" field, I elaborated why the add-on should not have been rejected:

- "There is currently a lack of community demand for this add-on scenario."
  I showed that the extensions for the other browsers have thousands of users (numbers + link).
- "There is not currently a demand for this item in the gallery at this time."
  I showed that a third-party site (Softpedia) has listed my extension, with over 1k downloads (+link to site)

Finally, I kindly requested them to reconsider their review status.

After 3 hours, this addon submission was rejected, and the original submission **approved**!

> Thanks for your submission to the Internet Explorer Gallery.  Your Toolbar or Extension was not posted due to the following reason:
>
> A duplicate or functionally similar add-on already exists on the Gallery.
>
> Hello,
>
> The addon was reviewed again and has now been approved for the gallery.
>
> Thanks again for your interest in the gallery!
>
> Regards,
> Internet
> Explorer Gallery Team

Note that after submitting your add-on, the page can already be viewed at IEGallery. However, until it's approved, you cannot find it through search.

Examples:

- Approved add-on: http://www.iegallery.com/addons/Details/16391
- Approved add-on, search result: http://www.iegallery.com/Search?q=%22Lyrics+Here%22
- Rejected add-on: http://www.iegallery.com/addons/Details/16396
- Rejected add-on, search (not found): http://www.iegallery.com/Search?q=%22Reply+to+add-on+rejection%22

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was looking into WIX after I posted this question. Is it possible to auto generate the *.wxs/xml file from an *.rgs or from Visual Studio Project or do I have to hand code the registry key values?

Comment: @TylerRafferty I have never used a rgs file. Adding registry keys is pretty straightforward using the [`<RegistryKey>`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrykey.html) and [`<RegistryValue>`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registryvalue.html) tags, though (see also: [How To: Write a Registry Entry During Installation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/write_a_registry_entry.html)). If you don't know how to start writing the wxs file at all, just search on Google/Github for wxs files. There are plenty of those.

Comment: @TylerRafferty I have edited my answer with an elaboration of how I got my extension listed.